# Tsumego elementary problem 157

Tags: go, tsumego

I tried to solve this tsumego, black is on the move:

[image]

it seems to me that white can kill black only if he wins the ko two times. Is that correct? After first ko win he will connect at 1-3 and after second win he will take at 3-2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black lives:

```
$$B 
$$ -------------------
$$ | . 1 . . X O . . .
$$ | O X . X X O . . .
$$ | . X X O O O . . .
$$ | O O O . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
```

White kills unconditionally:

```
$$W 
$$ -------------------
$$ | . 2 1 . X O . . .
$$ | O X . X X O . . .
$$ | 3 X X O O O . . .
$$ | O O O . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
```

This doesn't work for Black, either.

```
$$W 
$$ -------------------
$$ | . . 1 . X O . . .
$$ | O X 3 X X O . . .
$$ | 2 X X O O O . . .
$$ | O O O . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
$$ | . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't see the "black lives" sequence. I was only reading the sequence when black starts at 3-1 (right next to your "1"). I don't know why I missed this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think black should play 2-1 then 3-1 and 1-3 are miai for b life, no need for ko